# Cookie Manager Java

Tags: java, exception, cookiemanager

I need to send Http Requests for different domains and I need to maintain cookies through my code, so when I receive a Http response I read the headers to get all received cookies so I can use it in the next HttpRequest.

Now I have a problem with one of the domains. And I have added a cookie Manager which will accept all cookies. This domain specifically gives me an Invalid cookie name exception.

Is there any way so Java can maintain all headers and cookies for me automatically without any extra working from my side.

Answer (score 0):

I got a great explanation for my question on the following article [A Guide To HTTP Cookies In Java](http://www.baeldung.com/cookies-java)